# Ansible scp error - No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ansible, scp

I'm running a fairly simple Ansible script to copy a directory to all machines in a group.

```
- name: patch python patches
  hosts: group1
  user: root
  tasks:
     - name: scp the python files to all servers
       local_action: command scp -rp /data/patches_additional_files/16_1_20_002/* {{ ansible_ssh_host }}:/opt/lib/
```

When I execute the scp command manually the file transfers as planned:

```
command scp -rp /data/patches_additional_files/16_1_20_002/* localhost:/opt/lib/
```

when I execute the Ansible playbook it raises an error:

> "/data/patches_additional_files/16_1_20_002/*": "No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks ansible doesn't like the asterisk (*) anymore.
I looped over the directories from my python script and added each directory to the `scp` command.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the output of "whoami" and make sure the permissions is set properly. For example

```
   tasks:
     - local_action: command whoami
       register: result
     - debug:
         var: result.stdout
```

The *`scp`* command can't work as expected. The variable  *`ansible_ssh_host`* "reflects the host a task is delegated to". See [Delegation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation).

```
     - name: scp the python files to all servers
       local_action: command scp -rp ... {{ ansible_ssh_host }}:/opt/lib/
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the copy module instead?

```
tasks:
  - name: copy the python files to all servers
    copy:
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: /opt/lib/
    with_fileglob:
      - /data/patches_additional_files/16_1_20_002/*
```